# "ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database" Error in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I keep getting the error "ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database" when trying to connect to an Apache Derby database with a java program in Intellij 2023.1 Ultimate Edition via JDBC. Additionally when I try to test the connection while said database is activated I get the following error message:

```
DBMS: Apache Derby (ver. 10.15.2.0 - (1873585))
Case sensitivity: plain=upper, delimited=exact
Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver (ver. 10.15.2.0 - (1873585), JDBC4.2)
[XJ040][40000] Failed to start database 'C:/Documents/java 2/baby names/babynames-derby/babynames' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@42110406, see the next exception for details.
```

When the database is deactivated the test connection succeeds(but I cannot connect with java unless it is activated). I have tried everything from restarting my machine, to deleting the db.lck file, to deleting and reinitializing the project, to searching the task manager for an un-ended process. Nothing works. How exactly does one find and kill the conflicting process? I have seen similar problems to this one addressed for other IDEs and the answer seemed to be to find and kill the process via the terminal. Is there a terminal command for intellij that would allow me to find and kill the un-ended process?

below is the full error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Documents/java 2/baby names/babynames-derby/babynames' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528, see the next exception for details.
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:115)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Util.java:252)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2848)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(EmbedConnection.java:406)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(InternalDriver.java:630)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:295)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:922)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:132)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:253)
> at BabyNamesQuery.main(BabyNamesQuery.java:13)
> Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'C:/Documents/java 2/baby names/babynames-derby/babynames' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528, see the next exception for details.
> at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:299)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(SQLExceptionFactory.java:170)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:75)
> ... 11 more
> Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Documents\java 2\baby names\babynames-derby\babynames.
> at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:299)
> at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:294)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(BaseDataFileFactory.java:1942)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(BaseDataFileFactory.java:2900)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(BaseDataFileFactory.java:1883)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(BaseDataFileFactory.java:339)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:1989)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:527)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:45)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:460)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.bootServiceModule(RawStore.java:2880)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(RawStore.java:185)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:1989)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:527)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:45)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:460)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.bootServiceModule(RAMAccessManager.java:1332)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(RAMAccessManager.java:1035)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:1989)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:527)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:45)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:460)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(BasicDatabase.java:945)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(BasicDatabase.java:773)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(BasicDatabase.java:182)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:1989)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(BaseMonitor.java:1817)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(BaseMonitor.java:1683)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(BaseMonitor.java:1516)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(BaseMonitor.java:988)
> at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Monitor.java:598)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(EmbedConnection.java:3994)
> at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2809)
> ... 8 more

Answer (score 0):

We have reported this issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16943). Please follow the ticket to stay updated on the progress.

Comment: Got a 404 error when navigating to the page.

Comment: This could be related to the page privacy settings. Please register on our platform, and I'll add your account to the thread:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135